# Error in storing the records in database

Tags: php

The following code for create edit form to update records. If I give all field it update correctly if I didn't change image it does not update the record. I want to update record without change image and also I want to update records by only changing the image.

```
<section id="main-content">
      <section class="wrapper">
        <h3><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> About Components</h3>

        <!-- BASIC FORM ELELEMNTS -->
        <div class="row mt">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
              <div class="form-panel">
                        <h3><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Team Update</h3>
                        <form class="form-horizontal style-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label">Title</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <textarea type="text" name="Title" class="form-control" required><?php echo $img['a_title']; ?></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label">Description</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <textarea type="text" name="Description" class="form-control" required><?php echo $img['a_description']; ?></textarea>
                                    </div>
                          </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label">Picture</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <div class="clear" id="im">
                                        <?php echo "<img src='/myproject/cp/image/".$img['a_image']."'height='50' width='50' >"; ?>
                                        <button type="button" id="remove" >remove</button>          
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="browse" style="display:none;">
                                        <input type="file" name="imageupload" value="imageupload"  />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label"></label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <input class="btn btn-theme" id="focusedInput" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="about.php">
                                <span>List view</span>
                            </a>
                  </form>
              </div>
            </div><!-- col-lg-12-->         
        </div><!-- /row --><?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $var=$_GET['a_id'];
    $file=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'myproject/cp/image/'.$img['a_image'];
    unlink($file);
    $var1=$_POST['Title'];
    $var2=$_POST['Description'];
    $image=$_FILES['imageupload']['name'];
    $root=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/myproject/cp/image/'; 
    $file_exts = array("jpg", "bmp", "jpeg", "gif", "png");
    $expo=explode(".", $_FILES["imageupload"]["name"]); 
    $upload_exts = end($expo);
        if ((($_FILES["imageupload"]["type"] == "image/gif")|| ($_FILES["imageupload"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")|| ($_FILES["imageupload"]["type"] == "image/png")|| ($_FILES["imageupload"]["type"] == "image/jpg"))&& ($_FILES["imageupload"]["size"] < 2000000)&& in_array($upload_exts,$file_exts))
        {
                if ($_FILES["imageupload"]["error"] > 0)
                {
                    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["imageupload"]["error"] . "<br>";
                }
                else
                {
                    $image= rand(0,9999).'.'.$upload_exts;
                    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["imageupload"]["tmp_name"],$root.$image);
                    $sql=mysql_query("UPDATE about SET a_title='".$var1."',a_description='".$var2."',a_image='".$image."' WHERE a_id='".$var."'") or die(mysql_error());
                    echo "<meta http-equiv=refresh content=\"0; URL=about.php\">";
                }
        }       
}
?>
```

Comment: where you have written the code for remove

Comment: the code is in jquery code as follow <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $( "#remove" ).click(function() 
 {
   $( "#im" ).hide();
   $("#browse").show();
  });
});
</script>

Comment: what you want exactly ? delete the file or hide... and what about the code you wirtten in PHP to remove a file

Comment: as @RahulMishra said , provide some php code and some more information about what you really want to do.

Comment: i coded for edit page i want to show the previous details on that i edit and save.now all the above things are done but if i don't change image it save successfully but image already stored get delete.so i want to delete image after remove button is clicked.

Comment: @mageshkumar use my edit from the answer i did posted.

Answer (score 1):

As you said in comment , when you save the edits all other details get saved but your image get's removed even if you haven't changed it , clearly it's your php code , even before checking that if you are submiting an image or not you already doing an `unlink` on it , you have to use the edit below :

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $var=$_GET['a_id'];
    $file_del =$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'myproject/cp/image/'.$img['a_image'];
    $var1=$_POST['Title'];
    $var2=$_POST['Description'];
    $image=$_FILES['imageupload']['name'];
    $root=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/myproject/cp/image/'; 
    $file_exts = array("jpg", "bmp", "jpeg", "gif", "png");
    $expo=explode(".", $_FILES["imageupload"]["name"]); 
    $upload_exts = end($expo);
        if ((($_FILES["imageupload"]["type"] == "image/gif")|| ($_FILES["imageupload"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")|| ($_FILES["imageupload"]["type"] == "image/png")|| ($_FILES["imageupload"]["type"] == "image/jpg"))&& ($_FILES["imageupload"]["size"] < 2000000)&& in_array($upload_exts,$file_exts))
        {
                if ($_FILES["imageupload"]["error"] > 0)
                {
                    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["imageupload"]["error"] . "<br>";
                }
                else
                {
                   unlink($file_del);
                    $image= rand(0,9999).'.'.$upload_exts;
                    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["imageupload"]["tmp_name"],$root.$image);
                    $sql=mysql_query("UPDATE about SET a_title='".$var1."',a_description='".$var2."',a_image='".$image."' WHERE a_id='".$var."'") or die(mysql_error());
                    echo "<meta http-equiv=refresh content=\"0; URL=about.php\">";
                }
        }       
}
```

Comment: thank you but now the changes made in other field didn't save. as well it does not redirect too. plz hel me to come over from this problem.

Comment: it does not save my record if i don't change the image. if only i change image it save my values if not it doesn't save. help me

Comment: try to turn on errors by using :  ini_set('display_errors',1); ,, and let me know if you get any error. code seems fine , i have removed the comments try without comments i inserted

Comment: waiting for your reply please  reply me "I want to update record without change image and also i want to update records by only changing the image."